# Running a python script (.py file) from PC1 to PC2 through C#

Tags: c#, python, winforms, wcf, sockets

Again I need your help with some ideas (not implementation, only advice) with the following plot:

Let's say I have two computers in a company (connected to a network) which I want to work together through a C# application:

**PC1** - C# windows forms application installed which will send a "ping"/"message" to the second PC
**PC2** - C# windows forms application which waits for a message/ping/whatever from the first PC. After receiving, he will execute the script.

I don't need this "communication" to be 100% realtime, I only need to "poke" the other one 1 or 2 times.

Anything I know wouldn't be a clean solution. I am considering WCF OR Sockets, I only read a tiny bit about each.

What would you do? What communication protocol would you choose?

Answer (score 0):

Do it step by step. First try to make a program for executing that script. Try with the method Process.Start.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx

Second step would be to send a message to that program from another in the second computer. If the connection is available by TCP and the computer with the script has an static IP, I would use sockets for sure. It's just sending a signal message for executing the first step code.